# second dropdown based on selection of first dropdown using script and PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, html-select

The first dropdown box will be populated when the page loads based on values from a database. The second dropdown box should display a set of values based on the selection from the first dropdown box. I know there have been similar questions asked on here before, but I haven't found a solution that matches my scenario.

UI code:

```
<tr>
<td><label for="taProj"><?php echo t('Project')?>:</label></td>
<td><select name="taProj" id="taProj" onchange= "get_module()">
<option value="" >-------------------------</option>
<?php   foreach ($tap as $row){?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['proj_id']; ?>" ><?php echo $row['proj_name'];?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="taModule"><?php echo t('Module Name')?>:</label></td>
<td><select name="taModule" id="taModule" >
<option value="" >-------------------------</option>
<?php   foreach ($tam as $row){?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['mod_id']; ?>" ><?php echo $row['mod_name'];?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select></td>
</tr>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function get_module(){      
        var projid = document.getElementById('taProj').value;
        alert(projid);
    }   

</script>
```

mycontroller.php

```
public function sample(){
        echo $_GET['projid'];       
    }
```

its working properly.. 
My need is...

How to call mycontroller.php file function sample() and 
how to pass the javascript value to the php function parameter.

I new in the script and jquery. please any suggest me... thanks

Kumar

Comment: call function module???you mean get_module()??

Comment: you can do it through ajax request

Answer (score 1):

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function get_module(){      
     var projid = document.getElementById('taProj').value;
     $.ajax({
        url : //ur controller path/methodname(module),
        data : "id="+projid,
        method : 'POST',
        success : function(data) {
             //here you will get response from your controller method and manipulate as per your use..
        }
    })
 }   

 </script>
```

**mycontroller.php**

```
  public function module(){
    echo $_POST['id'];       
}
      or
 public function module($id){
    echo $id;       
}
```

**url path for calling function**

```
  url : '<?php echo str_replace('&amp;', '&', $this->action('model')); ?>',
```

more info refer [this link](http://www.concrete5.org/community/forums/customizing_c5/calling-a-controller-function-from-a-block-view/)
hope it may help you.

Comment: hi i actually i using concrete5 cms. its have own properties of mvc. so i want pass the projid value to my controller php file. here no need to call mention the php file just use the $this->action('function name'). so will you help me how to call the function through php code...

Comment: i don't know about concrete5 cms. but this code will work in your cms. just give url path. which i have updated in my answer check

Comment: i updated my answer check and refer given link also there he has called controller method from ajax... you can do same way

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but its not work for my scenario... the link solution is different. thanks a lot once again

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Simple jquery Ajax.

Javscript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function get_module(){

var projid = document.getElementById('taProj').value;

//Pass your value to controller.php through ajax

$.ajax({
  url:"controller.php",
  data:{id:projid},
  type:"get",
  success:function(data){
    $("#taModule").html(data);  //inserts your data into second select field
}
});
</script>
```

Controller.php:

```
 <?php
  $id = $_GET['id'];

  //enter your DB query to retrive values using $id

 echo "<option value=".$demo['id'].">".$demo['value']."</option>";

?>
```

Comment: hi i actually i using concrete5 cms. its have own properties of mvc. so i want pass the projid value to my controller php file. here no need to call mention the php file just use the $this->action('function name'). so will you help me how to call the function through php code...